# Sorting terms individually for each post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, order

I have a custom taxonomy named `author` containing multiple terms.
The default output order in the front end is alphabetically. But I like the authors to be ordered individually per post, e.g.

First post: Sam Meyer, Isabel Plim, Joseph Peters

Second post: Isabel Plim, Joseph Peters, Sam Meyer

I found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38961/control-term-order-on-a-per-post-basis) with a relatively detailed answer but I didn’t manage to get it to work.

Questions:

— Where do I have to put the »HTML for the term order metabox«?

```
<?php
echo '<ul id="the-terms">';
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   echo '<li class="item" id="term-'.$term->term_id.'">'. $term->name .'</li>';        
   }
   echo '</ul>';
   echo '<a href="javascript: void(0); return false;" id="save_term_order" class="button-primary">Update Order</a>';
?>
```

— Does the »JavaScript to make the above list sortable and save the order using ajax« has to be enqueued like so?

```
<?php function myscript() { ?>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
// Make the term list sortable
    jQuery("#the-terms").sortable({
        items: '.item',
        placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        distance: 1,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move'
    });
    // Save the order using ajax        
    jQuery("#save_term_order").live("click", function() {
        var postID = $("#post_ID").val();
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {
        action:'save_term_order', 
        cache: false, 
        post_id: postID,  
        order: jQuery("#the-terms").sortable('toArray').toString(),
        success: ajax_response()
       });
       return false; 
    });   
});

</script>
<?php } ?>
<?php add_action( 'wp_footer', 'myscript' ); ?>
```

Comment: If this is one question specifically regarding the third-party code provided in the other answer, I feel it should be posed in that answer's comments. If your questions are individual and unrelated, _"How do I create a metabox?"_ and _"How should I enqueue scripts?"_ have already been answered, and a little research should yield results. The Codex entries on [`add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) may also prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

> — Where do I have to put the »HTML for the term order metabox«?

Take a look at the [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) codex page, the example there shows you how to put a metabox on your posts admin pages.

Regarding your second question:

> — Does the »JavaScript to make the above list sortable and save the order using ajax« has to be enqueued like so?

You should be using admin_enqueue_scripts, from within a plugin. Something like this:

```
function my_admin_scripts(){
  // js
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_admin_js', plugins_url('myPlugin/js/my_admin.js') );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts' );
```

Both of these bits of code should be called from a plugin. Wordpress has a guide to creating plugins at [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)